# Possibilities communication beetwen several Windows 8 RT devices (running same app) C# WI-FI

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8, wifi-direct

I want to develop an app, which will be running on tablets with Windows 8 (RT). One tablet with this app should be a "master" tablet and this tablet will communicate with other tablets "slave" (running same app). Master tablet should send data to slaves tablets (slave tablet display this received data) and slaves tablets will send data to master. Master collect this data and create some graph etc... I hope you understand. (resume: several same W8 RT app communication with each other)

Can tablets with W8 RT (running same app) communication WI-FI Direct? What´s possibilities are in C#?

Thx for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 includes a capability to help you establish connections between copies of your app running on different devices. That capability is called PeerFinder.

Currently PeerFinder can find other devices using NFC (tap the two devices together) or using WiFi if both devices support Wifi Direct. After the initial handshake, both devices  communicate using sockets.

**The Proximity Sample shows basic use of PeerFinder:**
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731

**PixPresenter is a sample app that uses PeerFinder and exchanges images between devices:**
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PixPresenter-Code-sharing-39ed631f

**PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes tells you what methods are currently available for discovering other devices:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.supporteddiscoverytypes

Hope that helps.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Answer (score 0):

If it's local network, you can use raw TCP communications and use UDP discovery to identify the master.

If it's a more distributed setup like the internet or separated network areas, I'd recommend you have a look at Microsoft Azure Queue Storage services explained [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/). This will allow a distributed and redundant master-slave model.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement, if anytime you need to emulate NFC you can use a specific sample driver : 
[Windows 8.1 : How to use Near-Field Proximity API without NFC hardware](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2013/11/22/using-windows-8-1-near-proximity-api-without-nfc-hardware.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Stéphanie

Answer (score 0):

Also, here you will find a WinRT lib that you can use to help you tranfer data/files between Windows 8 peers running the same application, using Wifi-Direct : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2013/12/11/win8-1-transfering-a-file-between-2-peers-using-wifi-direct-and-proximity-api.aspx

Best regards